# iOS: Volume change long press

Tags: ios, iphone

I receive notification on volume change using following line of code.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enableVoice:) name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

- (void)enableVoice:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    float volume = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"%f", volume);
    // Do stuff with volume
}
```

How can I detect if volume change is via long press i.e. rate of change of volume is high enough to be called long press and duration of long press is 2 sec+?

Comment: volume button on left side of iphone.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there a noticeable time difference between the number of times per second the notification fires when the button is held down vs. when tapped as rapidly as possible?

Comment: yup detected via it. Thanks

Comment: @AyazAlavi I don't know see a significant difference between the 2. Is there any way to detect long press

Comment: @AyazAlavi Please elaborate how did you manage to detect long press?

Comment: @AyazAlavi PLEASE sir answer. It will help me a lot! how to detect Long Press